# Linear Layout and cardView

Tags: java, android

I am new to android app development. I know this is a very basic question, but I was wondering what the benefit of having a `LinearLayout` is when creating a UI. I understand it helps organize its children horizontally or vertically, but does it have any other benefits while creating a UI?

I was wondering this since I ran into some problems with padding while trying to design a UI using a card view without a `LinearLayout`

Comment: You asked whether it has any other advantages, but compared to what?

Comment: Just using card view without linear layout

Comment: That is a terrible title for a question you might wanna edit your title with actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's responsive. Responsive to various display sizes.

However LinearLayout is one-dimentional. If you want to control layout two-dimentionally, you need to nest LinearLayouts.

For such case, you are recommended to use ConstraintLayout rather than LinearLayout.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response! Why would ```ConstraintLayout``` be better than ```LinearLayout``` while controlling layouts 2 dimensionally? Thanks.

Comment: @CodingChap As I mentioned in my answer, one of the reason is LinearLayout needs to be nested while ConstraintLayout doesn't.

Comment: Ah ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If your markup is simple and LinearLayout is enough for you, use it.

If your layout is getting more complex and you have to nest LinearLayout, then it is better to use ConstraintLayout.

You should not use ConstaintLayout everywhere, as it is much harder to render than LinearLayout or FrameLayout, and if you can see it with non-nested layouts, replace it.